# Enviar e-mail por java

Tags: java

Estou tentando enviar e-mail por java mas estou tendo um erro com o smtp. Meu código:

```
try {
        SimpleEmail mail = new SimpleEmail();

        mail.setFrom("teste.email.send@gmail.com", "Teste");
        mail.setSubject("E-mail exemplo");
        mail.setMsg("E-mail de exemplo");
        email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
        mail.setAuthentication("teste.email.send@gmail.com", "********");
        mail.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");

        mail.addTo("meu.email@gmail.com", "Lucas Souza");
        mail.setSmtpPort(587);
        mail.send();

    } catch (EmailException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Email.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

O erro que da é na linha do mail.send():

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:467
```

Queria saber por que meu erro é no smtp 465 se estou colocando 587.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve setar TLS ao invés de SSL:

```
try {
        SimpleEmail mail = new SimpleEmail();

        mail.setFrom("teste.email.send@gmail.com", "Teste");
        mail.setSubject("E-mail exemplo");
        mail.setMsg("E-mail de exemplo");
        mail.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
        mail.setAuthentication("teste.email.send@gmail.com", "********");
        mail.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");

        mail.addTo("meu.email@gmail.com", "Lucas Souza");
        mail.setSmtpPort(587);
        mail.send();

    } catch (EmailException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Email.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Melhorou, agora ele ao menos da o erro no port 587 aheuhaueh

Answer (score 0):

Tenho um exemplo que funciona perfeitamente, segue abaixo:

```
   public static void sendEmail() throws EmailException {

        SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
        // Utilize o hostname do seu provedor de email
        System.out.println("alterando hostname...");
        email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");

        // Quando a porta utilizada não é a padrão (gmail = 465)
        email.setSmtpPort(465);

        // Adicione os destinatários
        email.addTo("karanalpe@hotmail.com");

        // Configure o seu email do qual enviará
        email.setFrom("karanalpe@gmail.com", "Karan User");

        // Adicione um assunto
        email.setSubject("Lembrete de senha");

        // Adicione a mensagem do email
        email.setMsg("Lembrete de senha karanalpe ");

        // Para autenticar no servidor é necessário chamar os dois métodos abaixo
        System.out.println("autenticando...");
        email.setSSL(true);
        email.setAuthentication("seuEmail@gmail.com", "suaSenha");
        System.out.println("enviando...");
        email.send();
        System.out.println("Email enviado!");
    }
```

No pom.xml:

```
   <dependencies>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>     

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
```

Vide post: http://karanalpe.com.br/tecnologia/back-end/enviando-email-com-o-java/

Comment: Continua com o mesmo erro aqui =(

Comment: Lucas... Acabei de testar na minha máquina e funcionou. Você abriu o post que eu disponibilizei? Baixe esse projeto e teste: https://github.com/karanalpe/envio-email

Comment: Não esqueça de alterar esses dados: "email.setAuthentication("seuEmail@gmail.com", "suaSenha");"